# Implementing method in a functional style

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following method:

```
private List<string> CreateSegments(string virtualPath)
{
    List<string> segments = new List<string>();
    int i = virtualPath.IndexOf('/', 1);
    while (i >= 0 && i < virtualPath.Length)
    {
        var segment = virtualPath.Substring(0, i);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(segment))
        {
            segments.Add(segment);
            segments.Add(VirtualPathUtility.Combine(segment, "default"));
        }
        i = virtualPath.IndexOf('/', i + 1);
    }
    segments.Add(virtualPath);
    segments.Add(VirtualPathUtility.Combine(virtualPath, "default"));

    return segments;
}
```

Basically, it creates path segments which I will use to check if a file exists in any of those segments. Like this:

```
string[] extensions = GetRegisteredExtensions();
HttpServerUtilityBase server = HttpContext.Current.Server;
List<string> segments = CreateSegments(virtualPath);

// check if a file exists with any of the registered extensions
var match = extensions.SelectMany(x => segments.Select(s => string.Format("{0}.{1}", s, x)))
.FirstOrDefault(p => System.IO.File.Exists(server.MapPath(p)));
```

All the above code looks like it could use some clean up and optimization, but I'm looking for a way to use `LINQ` if possible to generate the segments.

Something like: `var segments = virtualPath.Split('/').SelectMany(...)` and get a result similar to the following:

```
/path
/path/default
/path/to
/path/to/default
/path/to/file
/path/to/file/default
```

Where `virtualPath` would contain the value `"/path/to/file"`

**EDIT:** Changed `string.Format("{0}/{1}", ...)` to `VirtualPathUtility.Combine(..., ...)`

Any ideas?

Comment: use `Path.Combine` instead of `string.Format("{0}/{1}"`

Comment: What's the input that generates the example output you provided?

Comment: input would be the value `"/path/to/file"`. I also updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick.  It is not the most succinct code but it seems very readable to me.  It uses string concatenation because for short strings, like paths or URLs, it is faster than any of the alternatives.

**Edit: fixed and tested.**

```
var query = path.Split(new[] {'/'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Aggregate(new List<string>(), (memo, segment) => {

        memo.Add(memo.DefaultIfEmpty("").Last() + "/" + segment);

        return memo;

    }).Aggregate(new List<string>(), (memo, p) => {

        memo.Add(p);
        memo.Add(p + "/default");

        return memo;

    });
```

Comment: I really like this approach. I'll try it out and see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

One way would be to incrementally select the path segments, then "join" it with an empty string and `"/default"` to get the two variations:

```
string path = @"/path/to/file";

string temp = "";

var query = path.Split('/')
                .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
                .Select((p) => {temp += ("/" + p); return temp;} )
                .SelectMany(s => new[]{"","/default"}.Select (d => s + d) );
```

Comment: Nice solution. You can type `path.Split(new []{Path.DirectorySeparatorChar}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` to make it work on both Unix and Windows machines. Use `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` instead of `"/"` and also consider `Path.Combine` instead of string concatenation

Comment: @IlyaIvanov good points.  I'm also trying to figure a way to do it without the `temp` variable.  Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @IlyaIvanov since the input is a URI segment and not a file system path I don't think `Path.DirectorySeparatorChar` applies.  Since the separatos is not platform-dependent I think hard-coding it is acceptable.

Comment: @Bobson I'm not familiar with that method.  If you mean `Aggregate`, that won't work as it returns a single result, not a collection.

Comment: @DStanley - You're right, I was misremembering.  Sorry about that.

Comment: I really like this answer as I don't have to define an extension method.

Comment: @DStanley a solution without the `temp` variable would be perfect.

Comment: Using a mutable variable like that is very non-functional and I think it borders on abusing LINQ. I would probably try to think of a better solution before using this.

Comment: @daptia What do you have against defining extension methods? Using the right extension method can make your code more readable.

Comment: @svick I agree. I don't have any problems defining extension methods. I just wanted to avoid it if I didn't have to... Actually, when I tried this approach I came back with second thoughts.

Answer (score 2):

If you first define an extension method like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<int> SplitIndexes(this string subject, char search)
{
    for(var i = 1; i < subject.Length; i++)
    {
        if(subject[i] == search)
        {
            yield return i;
        }
    }

    yield return subject.Length;
}
```

Then you could do this:

```
var endings = new string[] { string.Empty, "/default" };
var virtualPath = "/path/to/file";
var results = 
    from i in virtualPath.SplitIndexes('/')
    from e in endings
    select virtualPath.Substring(0, i) + e;
```

Or if you prefer query syntax:

```
var endings = new string[] { string.Empty, "/default" };
var virtualPath = "/path/to/file";
var results = virtualPath.SplitIndexes('/')
                         .SelectMany(i => endings.Select(e => virtualPath.Substring(0, i) + e));
```

The result will be:

```
/path
/path/default
/path/to
/path/to/default
/path/to/file
/path/to/file/default
```

As others have suggested, you can this in a more platform independent way by using `Path.Combine`, like this:

```
var endings = new string[] { string.Empty, "default" }; // Note: no / before default
var results = 
    from i in virtualPath.SplitIndexes(Path.DirectorySeparatorChar)
    from e in endings
    select Path.Combine(virtualPath.Substring(0, i), e);
```

Comment: Thank you! One thing to note is that the `virtualPath` value is actually a virtualUrl, so the separator character is always the same "/" across all platforms (if I understand correctly).

Comment: @daptia In which case, feel free to disregard the last comment.

Answer (score 1):

The higher-order function you're looking for is called [scan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum). There is no such function in normal LINQ, but you can find it in [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/). Using that, your code could look like this:

```
private List<string> CreateSegments(string virtualPath)
{
    return virtualPath.Split('/')
                      .Scan((s1, s2) => s1 + '/' + s2)
                      .Skip(1)
                      .SelectMany(p => new[] { p, p + "/default" })
                      .ToList();
}
```

This assumes your path will be always an absolute path starting with a `/`. For relative paths, you will need to remove the `.Skip(1)` part.

If you don't want to get MoreLinq just for this one method, you can just copy [its source](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/MoreLinq/Scan.cs) into your project.

Answer (score 0):

The provided answers so far are more succinct, but this is what I came up with:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> PossiblePaths(string basePath)
{
    return PossiblePaths(basePath.Split(new[] { "/" }, 
                         StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
}

private static IEnumerable<string> PossiblePaths(IEnumerable<string> segments, 
                                                 string current = "/")
{
    if (segments.Count() == 0)
    {
        return new string[0];
    }
    else
    {
        string next = current + segments.First();
        return new[] { next, next + "/default" }
                         .Concat(PossiblePaths(segments.Skip(1), next + "/"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<string> EnumerateSegments( this IEnumerable<string> segments )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder() ;
  foreach ( string segment in segements )
  {
    sb.Append( Path.DirectorySeparatorChar ).Append( segment ) ;
    yield return sb.ToString() ;
    int n = sb.Length ;
    sb.Append( Path.DirectorySeparatorChar ).Append("default") ;
    yield return sb.ToString() ;
    sb.Length = n ;
  }
}
```

ought to do you.

Comment: Why would you do this instead of using `foreach`?